# Jquery Toggle Has Erratic Behaviour

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

```
$(function () {
        $("div").toggle(function () {
        $(".green").slideDown('medium');
     }, function () {
        $("div").click(function () {
            $(".green").slideUp('medium');
            });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bVr2r/181/

The behaviour is after one click it expands and it only respoonds to the second click erratically.

I figured I have to use .stop() in some way but I don't really know how. I used it in this way
$(".green").stop().slideUp('medium');
however that stopped any animation behaviour altogether.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of JQuery do you use ? toggle changed.

Comment: `.toggle` function is deprecated in jQuery v1.8 and removed in jQuery v1.9.

Comment: You might be interested in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305318/code-breaks-when-updating-jquery-due-to-changes-in-toggle)

Answer (score 2):

You are binding another click function in the toggle function.

Delete the click function and change it to:

```
$(function () {
    $("div").toggle(function () {
        $(".green").stop().slideDown('medium');
    }, function () {
        $(".green").stop().slideUp('medium');
    });
});
```

and it will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/bVr2r/182/