# Nondeterministic jQuery .toggle() How to prevent this fluky behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Using jQ the `.toggle()` behaviour seems to depend on the location of the client mouse pointer at the time of page load events.  And that, in terms of reliable (Turin like) behaviour, is totally useless!!

For example hovering over an iframe video while the page loads *inverts* the toggle state. Each subsequent hover event has the reverse effect, hiding instead of

```
$("iframe").hover(function () {
   
             $('#sliderContainer').fadeToggle();
});
```

Initially I searched to find some mitigation. Am I correct to conclude that at some timepoint there will always be a risk of hover-toggle becoming inverted?

Also I've read in [SO that .toggle has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16863086/2455159), but don't see any indication of that on [jQ's website](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-duration-complete).  What's going on there?

Comment: If I was you I would look into `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ was deprecated and removed, not https://api.jquery.com/toggle

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks! which combos work?  Is there a rule (of thumb) for combining state and action?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen gave mouseenter and mouseleave a shot, but have the same problem.  Also tried `setTimeout()` to prevent those events from firing during/ before load, but no that doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

I still found `.toggle` to be non-deterministic with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Those mouse events do work with `display:none` and  `display: block`, with the provision that when the mouse is over the 'toggle' area for the time during page load, then the mouse has to leave the area and trigger the mouseenter event.

At least that is expected and dependable behaviour!  Then animation has to be added.